# Maven - how to wait at phase until port is being used

Tags: mongodb, maven, build, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I would like to add something in my pom.xml file that has the build wait at a certain phase (pre-integration-test to be specific) until MongoDB on the localhost is waiting for connections on port 27017.

Because integration tests during the `integration-test` phase require that calls be made to the MongoDB database.

Also the reason I need to wait is because I need to start the build AND the mongodb **in parallel** and therefore I *do not know* if mongodb will be up and running on port 27017 by the time I reach the `integration-test`phase.

Therefore, what is something I can use during the `pre-integration-test` phase to have the build wait?

Here are the plugins that execute the integration tests. I am using Spring Boot 1.3.0.M2:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```